# HTML & XML parser solutions for Kotlin Multiplatform?

Tags: kotlin, web-scraping, kotlin-multiplatform

I am working on a Kotlin Multiplatform project that involves HTML parsing for data extraction. While I have successfully implemented Ktor as the HTTP client, I am in search of a reliable and efficient HTML parsing solution compatible with Kotlin Multiplatform.

Could you please share insights, best practices, or any libraries that are well-suited for HTML parsing within the context of Kotlin Multiplatform development? I am particularly interested in experiences and approaches that have proven effective in similar projects.

Comment: I found this one, i think its what you expected. https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.html.

Comment: Not. These is "the inverse" of I want. I need parse HTML, these library do HTML.

Comment: It's not strictly compatible to KMM but the approach of this lib is the right one I guess: https://github.com/T-Fowl/ktor-jsoup . It adds a Jsoup parser to Ktor client. I'm also interest of an answer for your problem, also for KMM compatibility.

Comment: Checkout https://github.com/fleeksoft/ksoup. It offers functionality similar to jsoup, encompassing most of its features

Answer (score 1):

Recently I came across this KMP library [ksoup](https://github.com/MohamedRejeb/Ksoup)

Comment: This is much better github.com/fleeksoft/ksoup. It offers functionality similar to jsoup, encompassing most of its features